# How to download /var/log via ftp cpanel

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, apache-log-files, error-reporting

I have a cpanel based server and I want to download /var/log so I can analyze why the server crash yesterday. However, if I login as regular user I can't download the file because it doesn't give me access to root.

If I login as root, I can't do that. Is there an easy way in cpanel to download server log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need root access in terminal then copy them to whichever folder  has FTP access. Most hosting account allow terminal access when you verify your identity. Root access is another thing all together if you are on a shared host you're not getting root access. Contact your hosting company and ask them why the server crashed, if you can get root access if it's dedicated or cloud